# Attach ClassLibrary Project to External Application with VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have an ClassLibrary project who I need to attach to an external application (console app).

***I found some solutions here explaining exactly to do this what I'm doing, but in my case it's not working running from vs, looks like I need some delay to VS (AutoAttach) to the executable***

I tried to do the following, the app runs but the break points are not hit.

[image]

**But, If I run this process manually and (Wait for load) and attach my library to this process it works, but the requirement we need to do this automatically**

I'm also doing this, but with or without this running the Executable from VisualStudio the attach (debugging) doesn't work properly.

[image]

Comment: Did you import the executable into a Visual Studio solution?   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-an-executable-not-part-of-a-visual-studio-solution

Comment: @FletchZhou-MSFT thanks for the link, I tested here and partially solve my problem, one of my requirements it's to avoid add a new project to the solution, because it's a project template for the ClassLibrary and shouldn't have a 3rd party project there.
But I will present this today with another solution that I made too, using EnvDTE.Process and Attaching via Code with an external application (calling via Debug), Feel free to post your answer here, it's valid for some scenarios :) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If you've found a better solution to this case, you could also post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and thanks to the @Fletch Zhou help, I ended creating a Debugger Helper.

What I did was, create a new console app called DebuggerHelper, this app run my "Main application" who I need to attach the process, Wait (Sleep) and then Attach the running VisualStudio Instance to that EXE.

Then I added the new exe to the debug option on my ClassLibrary Project and Added this exe file as part of my project.
Then, when I run the class Library Pressing F5, he loads my External App, and Attach it perfectly :)

[image]

```
private static void AttachProcess()
{
    var localByName = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(_appName);

    MessageFilter.Register();
    var process = GetProcess(localByName[0].Id);
    if (process != null)
    {
        process.Attach();
        Console.WriteLine("Attached to {0}", process.Name);
    }
    MessageFilter.Revoke();
}

private static void StartProcess()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("start.bat");

    Console.WriteLine("Waiting to load the process...");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
}

private static Process GetProcess(int processId)
{
    // Visual Studio 2017 (15.0)
    var dte = (DTE)Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.15.0");
    var processes = dte.Debugger.LocalProcesses.OfType<Process>();
    return processes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ProcessID == processId);
}
```

Github solution:
https://github.com/thiagoloureiro/DebuggerHelper

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 1):

If the class library solution cannot have the executable project, we are still able to debug it.
For example, I got a class library called **ClassLibrary1**, the class in it is simple:
[image]

I also created a **console project** standalone, add **reference -> Browse -> find the ClassLibrary1.dll**.
Add the using statement and code like below: 
[image]

I put the breakpoint, run the console project and it could step into it.